# query with login name and login status control

Tags: asp.net

I am using **loginview** control for displaying logedIn user in asp.net ,in this control i have used **loginname** and **loginstatus** control.the problem is that,when i press f5 it directely displayes system loged username ie. my default system account username.i am getting confused what to do ! Is anyone having solution please share.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you correct... you get display "yourdomain/youraccount" ?

If so ... and you do not want to use windows authentication you should switch to forms authentication otherwise it uses the windows credentials...

one point to start looking is the webconfig...

```
<configuration>
<system.web>     
    <authentication mode= "[Windows/Forms/Passport/None]">
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

EDIT:
LoginName Control to Display Full Name instead of username
http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2009/06/16/loginname-control-to-display-full-name-instead-of-username.aspx

you should also make sure that you hooked up membership database...

HTH

Comment: actually i wanted to display logger name and status and aspcontrols(login name and status) taking default windows authentication so it displaying system username but,when i tried as per you say,controls are not working with it.is does not displaying name or status.

Comment: Added antother link from an article to display the full user name